# bind:clientHeight grows endlessly

Tags: html, css, svelte

I've created the following layout:

- desktop: two columns
- mobile: one column

There are 4 grey cards and one (the first) red. The dimensions of the grey cards depends on their content, the red one whould have the same height of the near card. To compure the size, I used svelte `bind:clientWidth` and `bind:clientHeight`.
It works but for some reason I needed to create a relative and then an absolute div, otherwise height grows endlessly.

So, this works perfectly on desktop (2 columns) but obviously not on mobile because of the absolute div.

[image]

[image]

Here the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-hill-0c5yk1) and below some relevant code:

```
<script>
  let containerWidth = 0;
  let containerHeight = 0;

  $: width = containerWidth;
  $: height = containerHeight;
</script>

<div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-3 border">
  <div
    class="position-relative w-100 h-100 p-3"
    bind:clientWidth={containerWidth}
    bind:clientHeight={containerHeight}
    style="width: {width}px; height: {height}px; background-color: red"
  >
    <div
      class="position-absolute top-0 start-0"
      style="width: {width}px; height: {height}px; background-color: #f7f9fa"
    >
        <div
          class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
          style="width: {width}px; height: {height}px; background-color: red"
        >
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In that case the red card has small height, it should have `height = 150px` but how can I do that?
On mobile probably is not necessary to bind height... How can I avoid to use relative/absolute to get the right dimensions of a div?

Comment: Do *not* merely link off-site, include all relevant code *within* the question itself.

Comment: @H.B. sorry, you are right, I added the code I think is is the most relevant

Comment: I think what you want could be achieved with a grid container https://svelte.dev/repl/46df9d5ee19b4dfd97b42f39c3c0232f?version=3.55.1